# JS multiple expression in ng-click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why doesn't this work?

```
<a ng-click="if(item.lp_iframe=='') ? href='{{item.lp_url}}' :
             playVideo(item.lp_iframe_id)" target="_blank">
```

I suspect I have to escape the `''`??

Comment: what is the error statement that you getting in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, your expression look like

`<a>ng-click="href='url'"></a>` // is the syntax is correct? Not

So try this

```
<a ng-click="if(item.lp_iframe=='') ? redirect(item.lp_url) :
             playVideo(item.lp_iframe_id)" target="_blank">

   $scope.redirect= function(url) ｛ 
      window.open(url)  
    ｝
```

or,

Try this

```
<a ng-click="clickevent()" target="_blank">

$scope.clickevent= function() ｛
  if(item.lp_iframe=='') 
       {   
        window.open(url)
       }
        playVideo(item.lp_iframe_id)
    ｝
```

Comment: $location is not defined

Comment: you need assign the $location in your controller

Comment: Object #<Object> has no method 'reload'

Comment: it make perfect sense but I gt an erorr, what does the reload do? and return true?

Comment: Sorry change that to  $route.reload();

Comment: I have change my code, it's look like good, our a tag should be `<a ng-click="if(item.lp_iframe=='') ? redirect(item.lp_url) :
             playVideo(item.lp_iframe_id)" target="_blank">
`

Comment: route is not define. btw I got it almost work when I use merely     $location.$path=url; but it became mysite.com/www.google.com

Comment: You did't define `route ` in your controller , But not a problem if the ` $location.$path=url;` is worked

Comment: it work but I gt a problem open it in a new window. it became mysite.com/www.google.com instead www.google.com what is the problem here?

Comment: Change $location.$$path to `$location.$$absUrl`

Comment: doesn't work. it make my chrome hang.. why don't use window to redirect?

Comment: You need to add ` $route.reload();   ` in there, i already said this

Comment: You need config the`$route` in your controller, same as hot you assign the $location in controller. Make any sense?

Comment: I did everything u said. but never mind, I got it work simply use window.open(url). again, why just don't use pure js to redirect?

Comment: If you work with like simple javascipt, then u can use window.open , ir u work with angularjs, then use $Loction and $rout, So please take a look the $location and $rout from google. simple

Answer (score 2):

move this to a function in scope, like this

```
$scope.foo = function() ｛
  // ...
｝

ng-click="foo()"
```

According to the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).

```
ng-click="expression"
```

Expression doesn't mean javascript, see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression.

Comment: @user3346088 why playVideo will cause problem? call it like playVideo(...) or $scope.playVideo(...).